# Problems Accessing USB Device Information in Node.js with npm USB Package on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, usb, libusb

I'm developing a Node.js application where I need to access information about connected USB storage devices, identify a specific one based on certain criteria, and transfer data to it.

I've encountered an issue using the npm [USB package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb) (version 2.11.0, which is the latest as of now). My application needs to run on Windows, but this package doesn't seem to work out-of-the-box due to dependencies on **libusb**. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require end-users to manually install additional drivers.

The specific data I need to filter the USB devices includes their serial number, product ID, and vendor ID. However, when I attempt to open a device, I run into the error (full logs available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EgMeNLnCJaPN7Um_w3Xd7zRFgH3-qL8T/view?usp=sharing))

I'm aware of the [USB package windows readme section](https://github.com/node-usb/node-usb#windows), but it simply doesn't work as expected. When trying to use `usb.useUsbDkBackend()`, I encounter the error

```
[ 0.006065] [00005310] libusb: error [windows_set_option] UsbDk backend not available
```

Considering this roadblock, my next idea is to develop a custom CPP NodeJS addon to handle USB device interactions. However, this seems like a significant undertaking, especially when the USB package appears to be close to fulfilling my requirements. I am hoping to find a solution that either makes the USB package work on Windows or a less labor-intensive alternative to writing a CPP addon.

I'm using Node.js v18.12.0 on Windows 11.